# Test Oracle SQL query against open source in memory database

Tags: c#, oracle, automated-tests, nunit, in-memory-database

I am using NUnit as my testing framework and I want to test an oracle query on specific testing data. I want to pull a dependency from nuget and run an in memory database to tests my query.
I assume my query is sql compatible so I think I do not need to test against oracle directly.

My search so far resulted in this [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_in-memory_databases) where it looks like there is no suitable in memory database.

I also found that "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" could be used for certain scenarios and I think mine is not one of them.

To give some context - here is a test implementation that would miss the database.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[TestFixture]
public class ExampleFixture
{
    public class JobData { public string Name { get; set; } }
    public string queryUnderTest = "select j.name, j.updated from T_JOB j where j.name like '%TEST%'";

    [Test]
    public void TestQuery()
    {
        var expected = new[] { new JobData { Name = "-TEST-" } };
        var Data = expected.Concat(new[] { new JobData { Name = "OTHER" } });

        var dataBase = MakeInMemoryDataBase();
        WriteTable(dataBase, "T_JOB", Data);

        var actual = QueryAndMakeJobs(dataBase, queryUnderTest);

        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected, actual);
    }

    private IEnumerable<JobData> QueryAndMakeJobs(object dataBase, string queryUnderTest) => Enumerable.Empty<JobData>();
    private void WriteTable(object imdb, string tablename, IEnumerable<JobData> data) {}
    private object MakeInMemoryDataBase() => null;
}
```

I am restricted to open source dependencies that I can pull from nuget.org.
My only other option would be to run an open source db from hub.docker.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, this isn't useful as a **unit** test; it is an **integration** test, as it fundamentally **needs** the appropriate server. Testing it against a completely different in-memory implementation is **not a useful test** - it tells you nothing about whether it will actually work, unless you're using that in-memory implementation for real in some scenario in your application. RDBMS implementations are touchy.

IMO you should focus on getting the appropriate *actual* RDBMS running in your test environment in some reproducible way.

Comment: I fully agree. I was careful not to call it a unit test since it clearly is not restricted to one unit of code. I do not have a staging for this I feel like running my own db is the only option - in memory should work for the query test.

Comment: @Johannes "in memory should work for the query test." - at which point, it is no longer testing the thing that you need/want to test

Comment: I think you have a point there. Would things be better if I launch a mysql db using docker and run the query against that?

Comment: @Johannes are you *running* against mysql? Oracle and mysql do not have the same syntax and behavior...

Comment: it looks like any test I can run would be meaningless. I can not run an Oracle instance at the moment. So my best test may just be to assert that the query string contains the fragments I expect.That would also break if future me "maintains" the query. I con not run oracle because I do not have a container for that just now. I have to table this until we have our staging up and running. Thanks for the help.